# Access a button on modal page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I've got a page that opens a modal (Page1.aspx).
That modal is another aspx page (Page2.aspx).

How can I declare in the opener page (or any other way), that a modal button, executes a button click in Page2.aspx.

I've tried to put:`$('#ButtonOK').click();` (as it's the buttons id), but on the parent page it isn't recognized.

How can I execute that click?

Many thanks.

MY CODE, PAGE1:

```
function createModal(f,w,h) {
            var dialogWidth = w;
            var dialogHeight = h;

        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false
            , bigframe: false
            , modal: true
            , width: dialogWidth
            , height: dialogHeight
            , autoResize: true
            , closeOnEscape: true
            , position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window.top }
            , open: function (event, ui) {
                $('#dialog').css('overflow', 'hidden'); //this line does the actual hiding
            }
            ,buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $("input[id$='ButtonOK']").trigger('click');
                },
                Cancelar: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $("#iframe").attr('src', f);
        return false;
    }

    function PermMV(usr) {
        createModal('new.aspx?usr=' + usr,350,450);
    }
```

`<div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
            <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" align="middle"></iframe>
        </div>`

PAGE 2:
`<div id="acrescenta2" title="Perm">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtuser1" name="txtuser" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="consprodtxt" />
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonOK" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonOK_Click" OnClientClick="ButtonOK_Click" Text="OK" CssClass="btnmv" />
        </div>`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IFrame` Like This,

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modal_dialog">
<iframe style=" width:100%; height: 100%;" id="ifrm" src="yourExternalPage.aspx" runat="server">
</iframe>
```

And Open This `Div` as a Dialogue using JQuery,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#BtnClick").live("click", function () {
        $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

1<>[Simple jQuery Modal Popup Window Example in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-jQuery-Modal-Popup-Window-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx)

2<>[Modal popup using jquery in asp.net](http://jqueryasp.net/open-a-web-page-in-modal-popup-in-asp-net-jquery/)

Comment: Thats what I'm doing.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on("click","element",function(args){
    //...
});
```

Try it

Comment: I've tried `$(document).on("click", "ButtonOK", function () {});`, with no result.

Comment: same thing. no result.

Comment: An explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#ButtonOK").trigger('click');
```

Comment: Try this:      $("input[id$='ButtonOK']").trigger('click');

Comment: An explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: What do you need to know more?